# jQuery get many anchor links to move randomly (console error)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I continuously keep getting this error, and I don't really understand why.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

I have gone back in and added a if statement to see if it exists before hand, but still error persists.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //setTimeout(function(){
        animateDiv();
   // },2000);
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    return [nh,nw];    
}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.MyContain a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    // if (oldq.length) {
     $('.MyContain a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });
    //}
};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
    var speedModifier = 0.009;
    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);
    return speed;
}
```

---

My mark-up is a bunch of text anchor links within `.MyContain` element. That I am trying to get just to move around randomly.

```
<div class="MyContain">
   <a href="#sample">Sample</a>
   <a href="#demo">Demo</a>
   <a href="#coffee">Coffee</a>
<!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Comment: Did you put a console.log(oldq) in the animateDiv to verify that the element is found?

Comment: `var oldq = $('.MyContain a').offset();` might return undefined?

Comment: Make sure `$('.MyContain a')` exists and it's returning only one element.

Comment: As far as adding the if an still seeing the error, from your snipplet, your if is *after* the place you do oldq.top, so natually if oldq is undefined, the error would happen before the if

Comment: can you post your  html?

Comment: And your `if` accesses a property of oldq. Should it ever be the case that oldq is undefined, even the `if`, that you intended to test whether something is causing your error, will cause a similar error "cannot access 'length' of undefined" ..

Comment: Your markup has three `a` tags inside it.  Which one are you expecting to get the `offset()` of?

Comment: the offset needs to be for a specific element your selector returns multiple

Comment: jQuery doesn't allow .offset() to be used on hidden elements. 
http://api.jquery.com/offset/